# See real IP through HTTP Proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, http

I'm setting a HTTP Proxy in a Java Application. In that application I test wether the proxy is working by querying http://api.ipify.org/.
However, I get my real IP address back instead of the one of the proxy. I checked with Wireshark, my computer sends the http request to the proxy which then returns my real ip address to me. I was wondering how that is possible. I'd also like to know if there is a way to check for this behavior without querying the api. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out there's a header being sent called: **X-Forwarded-For**, which contains your original IP.

It might be possible to either remove that request header or customize it, if you're trying to remove it, it may be tacked on by the proxy no matter what though and out of your hands.
Here's an interesting article that may help if you haven't seen it yet. [HTTP Requests from Java, add header and proxy information](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/making-http-requests-from-java/240160966). Another option may be to look into a different proxy provider.

For an alternate method to check if the proxy is working you should be able to use: InetAddress.isReachable(), you could check for a response back from any website such as Google.com, or a custom server you have on the internet. Unless you're trying to verify the proxy IP, you could still set up your own verification server, even if it's some freebie host.
InetAddress.isReachable may have some downfalls as mentioned here: [The "isReachable" method has not been worthy of using for me in many cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address)

This looks to be the most relevant to your question: [How to check if proxy is working in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030908/how-to-check-if-proxy-is-working-in-java) I also imagine you're trying to do something similar such as checking a proxy list, rather than using a paid service. It depends if the software is just for you or if it's going to be released and shared. If it's just you it might be worth purchasing a proxy that gives you anonymity.

Comment: Indeed I'm checking a proxy list which is supplied by the user. It's an educational project for school, so anonymity isn't really my concern. If it was, I'd use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found out what happened here.
The proxy seems to use the X-Forwarded-For HTTP flag. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For. So I guess the only way to really make sure is to query the api and see what's returned.

Comment: Yes, the service you're using to check your IP is proxy aware, so if that header is present, it returns the IP listed in that header.